Cypress doesn't find an element with dynamic id
I want to find an element and to type whose id is dynamic, but it doesn't work. Example.
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth MuiTextField-root css-zwqr57">
   <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-sizeMedium MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-colorPrimary MuiFormLabel-filled MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-sizeMedium MuiInputLabel-outlined css-1ald77x" data-shrink="true" for="input_filter_filename_b6c7474b-091b-4774-8bbc-9abea59e3123" id="input_filter_filename_b6c7474b-091b-4774-8bbc-9abea59e3123-label">Nome</label>
   <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl css-1sopxis">
      <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="input_filter_filename_b6c7474b-091b-4774-8bbc-9abea59e3123" maxlength="200" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input css-1pog434" type="text" value="">
      <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline css-1q73ugn">
         <legend class="css-14lo706"><span>Nome</span></legend>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>

The "input_filter_filename_" part does not change in the id
I tried the following:
cy.get('id').contains('input_filter_filename_')
   .type('my text')

But, dont types. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you want to select by an attribute, you need to add square brackets.
Something like cy.get('[id="value-of-attribute"]').
Furthermore, if you want to select just part of the attribute value, you need to use ^= which changes the selection from equals to startsWith.
cy.get('[id^="input_filter_filename"]').type('my-text')


To deal with the multiple element issue, along the lines of Aladin's solution - as a second example of traversal
cy.contains('fieldset', 'Nome')  // works even though "Nome" is in child span
  .prev('input')
  .type('my-text')


Many thanks for the reply. In my case, it is returning 2 objects with the same beginning of the Id. How do I type in the second element?

@Alex you can select a locator at the nth location using eq() -> https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq

Note that using .eq() can be problematic long term due to page changes or even reflow of the element layout.

For the case where you have multiple instances of the attribute, use the <label> to identify the required input.
The label is easily found by it's text.
It has a for attribute that points to the <input>, use the exact id value to get the input.
cy.contains('label', 'Name')
  .invoke('attr', 'for')                         // extract the id
  .then(id => {
    cy.get(`#${id}`).type('Guilherme')
  })

In the case where cy.contains('label', 'Home') also returns multiple elements, the app may have "responsive" copies of the element - one for desktop viewport and one for mobile viewport.
But only one will be visible at a time, so add :visible to the selector:
cy.contains('label:visible', 'Name')
  ...


Using Traversals
With this particular DOM you can also use traversals (and forget about id)
cy.contains('label:visible', 'Name')
  .next()                                     // div after label
  .find('input')                              // child of div
  .type('Guilherme')

